# Maximum number of else statements in C++

Tags: c++

I have some legacy code for a messaging system implemented with a huge `if/else if/else if`... block. When I wanted to add a new `else` block Visual Studio 2010 has "internal compiler error".

Do you know if is defined by the C++ standard or implementation defined maximum number of `else` statements? If is implementation defined where may I find the maximum number for Visual Studio 2010?

For historical reasons I can't change the code, even if the implementation is... not very wise.

Comment: Seems like you found it.  I highly doubt it is specified, they just assume no one will hit that limit (assuming such a limit exists) in a real program.

Comment: Can you try to compile it in a different compiler?

Comment: Only Visual Studio 2010 for PC and Xbox

Comment: you deserve a medal for reaching max number of else statements.

Comment: I just wanted to add one:) The medal should be given to the guy who designed the system:p

Comment: "For historical reasons I can't change the code" - then don't change it for historical reasons - change it for practical reasons, because you have to.

Comment: No one would accept a 10 years old function to be changed(I already tried)

Comment: @Felics Sounds like you have even more reasons to refactor the function to bring back to whoever told you that you can't change the function

Comment: Now you know why the original developer stopped there...

Comment: you just need to remove all "else" and put a "goto after_all_following_ifs;" at the end of each if-block. sounds like an even less risky change than adding a new else block.

Comment: All this time and I just realized, this is an interesting question, the inability to modify the code aside. Even finding ones self in such a malaise of if-then-else is bad enough, but to therefore find one's-self pondering this deserves an upvote. +1, sir.

Comment: The next interesting question is why you don't want to refactor the code...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I can personally attest to being in that position. I can feel the pain of wanting *desperately* to refactor it, but powers-that-be tying your hands because of cost analysis (one of several software development as a cost-center situations I've experienced in my career). It is a *sucky* position to be in, as it demonstrates utter lack of faith and commitment from said powers. I eventually left that job, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig: There are different levels of refactoring. In a message system I imagine that it is basically faking a `switch` statement with a sequence of ifs. I am not saying that the component/library/program be refactored, but that the implementation of the function can be improved (and considering that it can not be extended by other means, there is a strong point for argument that this should be changed)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh I concur. There are a lot of things we would do to address this. I'd probably float the idea of splitting the if-else chain into two and sending one to another function if mgmt was worried about per-case change velocity. Odds are the OP probably had to get something signed in blood to even be granted the go-ahead to add another `else if`. Some staffs are just that paranoid, especially the ones that have no idea how the code *works* (and the people that did have long-since-departed). As I said, software development as a cost-center just plain **blows**.

Comment: A chain of if / else with each using strcmp() would be really slow.

Comment: I recently encountered the `else if` chain limit in Visual Studio 2008 after adding several more `else if's` to a chain. They are a chain of string comparisons. I'm the one that added all of the `else's`. Originally, they didn't have those for some reason. So, the code would needlessly continue checking strings after finding a match. This is code that only runs once at start-up, I believe. So, it isn't crucial that it be fast, but I think I'm going to switch all of the `else's` to `goto's`. I was surprised that the compiler, apparently, considers each `else` to be a new nest level.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ Standard does not require a minimum. It has a recommended minimum, but not a required one.

> Nesting levels of compound statements, iteration control structures, and selection control structures [256].

Once the limit of an implementation is exceeded, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Don't you mean `maximum`? :)

Comment: @MihaiTodor No, he means minimum. It is the *real* question being asked here whether the OP knows it or not. Is there a standard-defined minimum number of depth required to be met by implementations for them to be in compliance with the standard? Johannes read right through the slightly backward question being asked, and addressed the *real* issue. (and +1 for the answer).

Comment: It is a minimal upper bound (minimax?).  The compiler is supposed to allow at least 256 levels (so the minimum acceptable value for the maximum number of levels is 256).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Visual Studio C++ compiler limits.

[MSVC compiler limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compiler-limits?view=msvc-170)